# Module import error using IDLE

Tags: python, path, python-idle

I'm an absolute beginner using IDLE (Python 2.6.4) to learn the basics. I recently found a [Python program](http://code.google.com/p/css-py) that I want to run but it throws an error although the code looks fine (i.e all modules exist):

```
from css.parse import parse

data = """
    em {
    padding: 2px; 
    margin: 1em;
    border-width: medium;
    border-style: dashed;
    line-height: 2.4em;
    }
    p { color: red; font-size: 12pt }
    p:first-letter { color: green; font-size: 200% }
    p:first-line { color: blue }"""

for rule in parse(data):
    print rule

for decl in parse(data)[0]:
    print decl
```

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named parse
```

How do I fix this? I'm using Snow Leopard.

Edit: I guess its a PATH issue, where should I place the modules, which directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your `test.py` script in the same folder as the folder, not **in** the folder.

So it should look like this:

```
../
 test.py
 css/
```

Comment: Yes it does. I guess its a PATH issue which I don't quite understand.

Comment: Can you post the link to this program?

Comment: So how exactly are you running this? I appears to be a module that you would import from a separate script.

Comment: I extracted/copied the 'css' folder on my disk, and created a new test.py file in the same folder to run an example (code.google.com/p/css-py/wiki/Examples) and I get this error. –

Comment: Ah, ok. I moved the test.py outside the folder, the original errors seems to have gone but now, uh, another similar error popped up: ImportError: No module named ply

Comment: Great, think I got it working, but the output is not what I'd expected though: 
--------------------------------------------------
WARNING: Token 'INVALID' defined, but not used
WARNING: Token 'DIMENSION' defined, but not used
WARNING: There are 2 unused tokens
Generating LALR tables
WARNING: 149 shift/reduce conflicts
PLY: PARSE DEBUG START

State  : 0
Stack  : . LexToken(S,'\n    ',1,0)
Action : Shift and goto state 4

....

Comment: Or maybe I'm not using the compatible ply version. Thanks anyway though, I'd better stop hear and learn more Python before asking for more help! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

A generic but useful reference regarding the way **Python module search path** is
[this brief but informative section of Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

The default paths and the environmental variables which allow configuring this important feature of the interpreter varies with different Operating Systems, so it is important to know this info for troubleshooting situations similar to that of Nimbuz.

Also the IDEs themselves can add yet another layer of configuration/indirection...