# Module import path

Tags: python, import, path, module

I'm unable to test-run a cssparser that I'd like to use.

**test.py**:

```
from css.parse import parse

data = """
    em {
    padding: 2px; 
    margin: 1em;
    border-width: medium;
    border-style: dashed;
    line-height: 2.4em;
    }
    p { color: red; font-size: 12pt }
    p:first-letter { color: green; font-size: 200% }
    p:first-line { color: blue }"""


for rule in parse(data):
    print (rule)
```

..gives an **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  method <module> in test.py at line 1
    from css.parse import parse
  method <module> in test.py at line 6
    from . import css, csslex, cssyacc
  method <module> in test.py at line 8
    from . import serialize
  method <module> in test.py at line 6
    from . import css
ImportError: cannot import name css
```

**Directory structure** (/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31):

```
/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/**csspy**/
|
+-- css/ (*has __init__.py*)
|
+-- uri/ (*has __init__.py*)
|
+-- test.py
```

**print(sys.path)** shows:

```
['/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/csspy', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python31.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages']
```

Comment: For others wondering what this relates to, here's the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774453/module-import-error-using-idle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is few steps I just tested.

- [readme](http://css-py.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README) says its python 2.5, so you need python 2.x series
- I have created a folder `C:/TEST/`
- I have downloaded all files from [css-py svn](http://css-py.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) to `C:/TEST/`, so `C:/TEST/css/` and `C:/TEST/uri/` folders exists now.
- I have downloaded [ply's tar gz file](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply-3.3.tar.gz) and extract **only** `ply` folder into `C:/TEST/css/`, so `C:/TEST/css/ply/` folder exists now.
- I have created `test.py` in `C:/TEST/` with the content

  ```
  from css.parse import parse
  print dir(parse)
  ```
- and I run it and the results is like this, without import errors:

  `C:\TEST>test.py`

  `['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']`

Hope this helps. sorry If my explanation is bad.

Comment: Many thanks for the step-by-step guide. But I did an additional step: converted all the files for 3.1 using 2to3 converter. My directory structure is similar but still no luck.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. See section A.10 at Dive Into Python 3: http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html and PEO 328: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Comment: er, that's PEP not PEO above.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `__init__.py` files in the `cssparser` and `css` directories, to turn the directories into packages?  Is there a `css/parse.py` file with some function or class named `parse` in it?  What's on your `sys.path`, and what's the current directory, when you execute `test.py`?  All of these questions may be important, and you give us the answer to none of them, so it's hard to be of any specific help!-)

Comment: sys.path: /Users/nimbuz/Documents/Python3/cssparser

Comment: Yes, it does have that file: all = ('csslex', 'cssyacc', 'css', 'serialize', 'parse') – Nimbuz 1 min ago

Comment: Exactly what Import error are you getting?  Something's wrong if your `sys.path` is just `/Users/nimbuz/Documents/Python3/cssparser`.  There should be a list of directories there.

Comment: SYSPATH: ['/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/csspy', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python31.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages']

Comment: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/csspy/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from css.parse import parse
  File "/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/csspy/css/parse.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import css, csslex, cssyacc
  File "/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/csspy/css/css.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import serialize
  File "/Users/nimbuz/Documents/python31/csspy/css/serialize.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import css
ImportError: cannot import name css

Comment: @Nimbuz, you never ask my first and most crucial question, so I repeat it: "Do you have __init__.py files in the cssparser and css directories?".  I see that shortly after my answer sykora asked exactly the same question in _his_ answer.  BTW, your latest listing of a weirdly capitalized `SYSPATH` is really very, **totally** different from what you claimed to have on `sys.path` in your first comment!  Why not edit your question with precise, non-contradictory and unambiguous answers to all of these questions?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the question now with all the details.

Comment: I don't think the css package you're trying to use can support 3.1 (it will need manual edits after your run of `2to3` on it, requiring somebody highly experienced in both versions of Python and ideally on the package itself too).

Comment: I can reproduce exactly the problem after running css through 2to3.  There appears to be a circular import problem which can be avoided by changing or even removing the `from . import css` in serialize.py.  I must admit it is escaping me at the moment what the problem there is.  However, things don't get much further after that  because you start to run into conversion problems in ply/yacc.

Comment: So, to concur with Alex, this package and its dependencies aren't a good choice to begin exploring Python 3.

Comment: Right, it seemed a small package that I could test-run, but it isn't. Thanks anyway Alex and Ned! :)

Answer (score 2):

python 3 version of css-py

http://ifile.it/v32n70s/css.zip

Comment: Thanks, but it still has tons of errors. Looks like it won't work on 3.1 after all. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `css/` have an `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call your own file `css.py`. Name it something else, like `css_test.py`. Delete the `css.pyc` file also.